# Powershell command to change default search scope for a site collection

Tags: powershell

In my site collection search scope, there are 2 scopes
1. All Sites (default scope)
2. MyCustomScope (custom scope)

I want to set "MyCustomScope" as default scope. Is it possible through powershell or any how.

I treid by display groups settings in search scope but it does not helped

Answer (score 0):

Save the below code as .ps1 and then run it.

```
Param
(
    [string] $webUrl,
    [string] $scopeName
)
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server.Search")

$site = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite" -ArgumentList "$webUrl";
$searchContext = [Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchContext]::GetContext($site);
$scopes = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Scopes($searchContext);

$group = $scopes.GetDisplayGroup($site.Url, "Search Dropdown");
$scope = $scopes.GetSharedScope($scopeName);

"Modifying default to $scopeName" 
    $group.Default = $scope;
    $group.Update();
    $site.Dispose();
```

**This can be run from command line by**

```
powershell -command .\UpdateSearchScope.ps1 "http://serverurl.com" ScopeName"
```

Souce: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2007Dev/Pages/Modifying%20the%20default%20Search%20Scope%20for%20a%20Site%20Collection%20programmatically%20using%20PowerShell.aspx